# MassTransit ESB and security

Tags: masstransit

MassTransit ESB supports any/all of the following security aspects?

- ACEGI
- JAAS
- PGP

As far as we analyzed there does not seem to any support for these security aspects in MassTransit ESB.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're looking for, you can create a custom serializer in MassTransit that does the encryption for you. A couple people have done so. The serializers are completely plugable, so have at it. Out of the box though, there is no support for these technologies.

See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/masstransit-discuss/TyrdqjYzjNg/MeJaXmhy1xIJ on the mailing list for an example discussion.